# The type 'float -> float' does not match the type 'float'

Tags: types, casting, f#

Just started learning F#, and I am attempting to generate and evaluate the first 10 terms of the Taylor series for *e*. I originally wrote this code to calculate it:

```
let fact n = function
    | 0 -> 1
    | _ -> [1 .. n] |> List.reduce (*)

let taylor e =
    let term n = (e ** n) / (fact n)
    [1 .. 10]
        |> List.map (term)
        |> List.reduce (+)
```

Which leads to an error because the `**` operator does not work for `int`.
Obviously I need to cast everything to `float` in order for everything to work correctly. So:

```
let fact (n: float) = function
    | 0.0 -> 1.0
    | _ -> [1.0 .. n] |> List.reduce (*)

let taylor (e: float) =
    let term (n: float) = (e ** n) / (fact n)
    [1.0 .. 10.0]
        |> List.map (term)
        |> List.reduce (+)
```

Which yields the compiler error:

```
EvaluatingEtotheX.fs(9,39): error FS0001: The type 'float -> float' does not match the type
'float'

EvaluatingEtotheX.fs(9,36): error FS0043: The type 'float -> float' does not match the type
'float'
```

(Line 9 is where `let term n = (e ** n) / (fact n)` is).

Why does this not work? What does this error mean exactly, anyway? Why does the compiler care that I'm passing a function which yields `float` and not an actual `float` value? Note that I just started learning F# so I am not familiar with why this won't work in this case.

Comment: Up-voting because I don't see any reason why someone down-voted it without even letting a comment to explain why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are mixing two types of syntax to define the `fact` function.

When using the `function` keyword, it implicitly adds an argument, which is then used in the defined branches. If you check the signature of your `fact` definition, you will see `float -> float -> float` instead of `float -> float`. The first float in your definition corresponds to `n`, the second one is added by the fact you use the `function` keyword.

You can use either the function keyword

```
let fact = function
    | 0.0 -> 1.0
    | n -> [1.0 .. n] |> List.reduce (*)
```

or an explicit match expression (compiler will be able to infer the type of `n` as `float`, no need to specify it manually)

```
let fact n =
    match n with
    | 0.0 -> 1.0
    | _ -> [1.0 .. n] |> List.reduce (*)
```

---

A side note, even though it will not be a practical problem in this case, comparing floats against exact values is generally not a good idea due to their binary representation. In your case it might make sense to keep `fact` operating on integers and then cast the result:

```
let term n = (e ** n) / (float (fact (int n))) // assumes fact : int -> int
```

Comment: as long as the arguments for `fact` are small enough to not produce an overflow...